# How to delete software installed with third party repository?

Tags: package-management, repository

I struggled getting VirtualBox to work in Ubuntu, so I removed it and installed it using a [third party repository](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox.org_contrib). I ran these commands:

```
wget -q -O - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.org.list'
```

I reconsidered and decided to remove VirtualBbox completely, however, I now can't remove it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
```

This gives the output:

```
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
```

I can still open VirtualBox and am unsure how to remove it. Also, I'm a complete newbie to Ubuntu, so I might have some fundemental misunderstanding of what repositories actually are or something similar.

Comment: The packages in the repository appear to be named either virtualbox**-6.0** or   virtualbox**-6.1**

Comment: In `terminal` do `dpkg -l *irtualbox* | grep ii` to determine that actual package name, then you can `sudo apt purge packagename`.